# Combine geom_boxplot with geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to combine a boxplot and a line plot using `ggplot2`. However, I am struggling to have lines for each group (`g`) connecting points across the categories on the x-axis.

To demonstrate the problem:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(letters[1:3],each=5), 
                 y = c(1:5,sample(10,5),1:5), 
                 g = rep(LETTERS[1:5],3) )

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_point(aes(colour = g))
```

[image]

I want to have a line connecting all `A` points, a line connecting all `B` points and so on.

I have looked at some answers here but I cannot incorporate them. They suggest using `group=1` but this will not suit my individual lines for each group in `g`. Is it possible using `stat_summary` maybe?

Comment: does adding `geom_line(aes(group=g))` do what you're looking for? It sure makes a cool looking shape...

Comment: Add a `set.seed` in your example code so we can replicate your image exactly when you call `sample`.

Comment: @Justin, aw man I was using `geom_line(aes(colour=g))`, and ggplot was having issues. Your suggestion solves the problem. It also does actually make a cool shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
... +  geom_line(aes(group = g))
```